# Auto deduced return types in forward declaration and mixing with old function syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

### Intro

In C++11 it's fine to declare a function like

```
auto times2(double num) -> double; // A
```

and define it like

```
double times2(double num) { // B
    return num*2;
}
```

The pair `A, B` can also be mixed the other way around.

C++14 introduces a third way

```
auto times2(double num) { // C
    return num;
}
```

### Q

1. Can style `C` be **mixed** with `A / B` in a **declaration/definition** pair ?
2. Can `C` **stand alone as a signature** (when the body of the function is not yet provided) ?

   ```
   // waiting for the definition to provide info on return type
   auto times2(double);
   ```

Comment: @BryanChen Obviously; I'm searching for an answer to elaborate on this. Maybe on the rules that provide deduction, when are they applicable and how the compiler needs to know return types to form stack frames around function calls. Then procced on declaration/definition pairs ...

Comment: @BryanChen: "`auto times2(double);` is useless." - looks to me like the proposal allows it - see [here](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3638.html), specifically "...allows non-defining declarations..."

Comment: I've addressed the *"uselessness"* of `auto times2(double)` in my answer, tl;dr -> it is certainly **not** useless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Mixing the new- and old-school

> `7.1.6.4p13` **`auto` specifier** `[dcl.spec.auto]`
>
> > Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type shall also use that placeholder, not a deduced type.

The above quotation makes it ill-formed to mix the *new* with the *old*.

More specifically any such mixing introduces an ambiguating since the only difference in the two declarations is the *return-type* of the function; two declarations where one uses `auto` and the other a non-deduced type `T` are, in other words, not referring to the same function.

```
auto f ();
auto f () { return 123; } // legal, return type is `int`

auto g ();
auto g () -> int;         // ill-formed, an invalid overload of `g` introduced

int  h ();
auto h ();                // ill-formed, an invalid overload of `h` introduced
```

---

#### Is a function declaration using C++14's return-type deduction equivalent of a forward declaration?

There are rules related to *automatic return-type deduction* in *C++14* that states that a function which yet hasn't had its return-type deduced is not usable in a context where such is required, that means that (*A*) below is not equivalent of an old-school declaration (ie. that a function can be used without yet having the definition).

```
auto foobar (double); // (A)

int main () {
  auto ret = foobar(3.14f); // ill-formed, return type is not known (yet)
}

...
```

> `7.1.6.4p9` **`auto` specifier** `[dcl.spec.auto]`
>
> > If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression the program is ill-formed. *...*

---

#### Are you saying that a declaration where the return-type is `auto` is... useless?

No, far from it, there are cases where a forward declaration certainly is required and contexts where the return-type mustn't be known until a later time, such as inside a template.

```
template<class T>
auto foobar (T);

template<class T>
auto barbaz (T val) { return foobar (val); }

template<class T>
auto foobar (T val) { return      val * 2; }

int main () {
  barbaz (1234); // return-type is int
  barbaz (3.1f); // return-tupe is float
}
```

Inside `barbaz` we must not know the return-type of `foobar` until we have actually instantiated `barbaz`, but without the a forward declaration of `auto foobar(T)` we couldn't refer to such name inside our template.

Comment: for your example, can't you just move `foobar` before `barbaz`?

Comment: @BryanChen in this trivial example that certainly would be a possibility, but what if the definition of `foobar` depends on `barbaz`? such as in this [silly example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33c2aacfd4967fc9).